# Use environment variables in the "generates" section of a Taskfile

Tags: taskfile

I have the following simple `Taskfile.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
env:
  OUTPUT_FILENAME: output.txt

tasks:
  my_task:
    cmds:
      - rm -f $OUTPUT_FILENAME
      - cp input.txt $OUTPUT_FILENAME
      - echo "That was it" >> $OUTPUT_FILENAME
    sources:
      - input.txt
    generates:
      - output.txt
      # - $OUTPUT_FILENAME
```

This works as expected. However, if I swap the comments in the `generates` section of the task, then the task is always triggered even if the output is already generated and up-to-date.

How can I use the environment variable in the `generates` (and similarly in the `sources` ) section?

Comment: Cross posted [here](https://github.com/go-task/task/discussions/1545) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is because environment variables are only available inside shell environments (i.e. the commands in your task). If you want to use variables in other parts of your task, you need to use the templating engine:

```yaml
version: "3"

env:
  OUTPUT_FILENAME: output.txt

tasks:
  default:
    cmds:
      - rm -f $OUTPUT_FILENAME
      - cp input.txt $OUTPUT_FILENAME
      - echo "That was it" >> $OUTPUT_FILENAME
    sources:
      - input.txt
    generates:
      - "{{.OUTPUT_FILENAME}}" # <-- here we use templating syntax to output the variable
```

---

*Sidenote:*

The above solution works because all `env` variables are currently made available to the templating engine as well as `vars`. This behaviour has previously caused confusion and I'd like to see it removed in a future major version. If this were the case, you would need to set up your variables like so:

```yaml
version: "3"

vars:
  OUTPUT_FILENAME: output.txt # <-- available to the templating engine
env:
  OUTPUT_FILENAME: "{{.OUTPUT_FILENAME}}" # <-- available as an env var in your shell commands

...
```

While this is more verbose, I think it is clearer what is going on, so this would be my preferred way of doing this today - regardless as to whether we make this change or not.